# Does MX Stop Spammers no longer work? What's an alternative?

Tags: registration, spam

Since I upgraded to EE 2.8.1, MX Stop Spammers has stopped working, with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in [path]/third_party/mx_stop_spammers/mcp.mx_stop_spammers.php on line 431
```

Before this, with 2.7.x, I was getting warnings about deprecated functions.

Is there a fix, and what's a good alternative for dealing with spam registrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get new version from my [git repository](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx_stop_spammers). New version is works with EE 2.8.1

Comment: Thank you.  I've been scratching my head trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Low NoSpam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-nospam) and have very few spam emails, comments, member registrations come through as a result. I have not upgrade any sites to EE 2.8 yet so I can't speak to if it is currently supported.

There are a bunch of other spam add-ons available [here](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=Spam&addon_version_support=ee2).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take another look at it. MX Stop Spammers is useful for finding and removing spammers that slip through my other defenses.